# How to setInterval with different time stop?

Tags: javascript

How to setInterval with different time stop? I used this code if else but it's not working. I would like the 3 balls stop with different time, the first one is 100ms the 2nd one is 150ms and the 3rd one is 200ms.

```
var  roll_balls, roll_balls;

    function SetInterval() {
        var balls, balls1, balls2;
        var timesRun = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(RollingBalls, 30 );


        function RollingBalls() {
            timesRun += 1;
            console.log('tick tock');
            if (timesRun === 100) {
                console.log('done');
                clearInterval(interval);

            }

            balls = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            var ballsDOM = document.querySelector('#balls-0');
            ballsDOM.src = 'numbers/ball-' + balls + '.png';

          else if (timesRun === 150) {
                console.log('done');
                clearInterval(interval);

            }

            balls1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            var ballsDOM1 = document.querySelector('#balls-1');
            ballsDOM1.src = 'numbers/ball-' + balls1 + '.png';

          else if (timesRun === 200) {
                console.log('done');
                clearInterval(interval);

            }

            balls2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            var ballsDOM2 = document.querySelector('#balls-2');
            ballsDOM2.src = 'numbers/ball-' + balls2 + '.png';
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your `if-then-else` block is not valid. There are three lines of code after the `then` part, and before the `else` part.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please fix the syntax error within your code (you can't have statements in between else-if statements. As of now, it can't be executed

Comment: I already have clearInterval, why should I still use the setTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Allow me to point out a few mistakes with both your syntax and logic which may guide you towards fixing your code

Your syntax is incorrect. Specifically, you cannot have anything between  *if* and *else if* blocks

```
if(timesRun === 100){
    // some code
} 
// Nothing can go here. If you uncomment these lines, you'll break the syntax
// balls = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
// var ballsDOM = document.querySelector('#balls-0');
// ballsDOM.src = 'numbers/ball-' + balls + '.png';
else if (timesRun === 150){
    // some other code
}
```

Next, you probably need correct your usage of *setInterval*:

- You are setting an interval of *30ms* on *RollingBalls* which means that it will be called every *30ms*. Now, inside *RollingBalls*, for ball 1, you are counting up to 100. So, ball 1 will stop at *30x100=3000ms or 3s* instead of *30ms*
- Also, when the first ball stops, it will clear the interval and hence all balls will stop. Effectively, all balls will stop after *3s*

To address this, I would recommend using different functions for all 3 balls and assign their own intervals. This will keep each function simple and you could late generalize them if you have a lot of balls ;)

```
var interval1 = setInterval(RollingBalls1, 30);
var interval2 = setInterval(RollingBalls2, 30);
var interval3 = setInterval(RollingBalls3, 30);
```

To clear the interval, you can use *setTimeout* inside each *RollingBalls* function to clear the interval for a specific ball at the specified stop time

```
function RollingBalls1(){
    function stopRollingBalls1(){
        clearInterval(interval1);
    }
    setTimeout(stopRollingBalls1, 100);
    // Do whatever you want to do with ball 1 here
}
```

If you want to continue with your original approach, change the counting logic, for example, count up to *100ms / 30ms = ~3* instead of *100* for ball 1 so that it stops at approximately *100ms* and clear the interval only after the last ball stops

You could also [measure the actual time elapsed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41633001/3829158) to compute stop time more precisely.

Finally, if you're animating the balls, you might want to increase the stop time to observe the animation